# MySQL doesn't connect to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing a local login database page on my pc under LAMP. And even though i can connect to mysql from terminal, I cannot do so from a  php script. I've looked all over online but every where i go its just the following code in one variation or another

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /* connect to the db */
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die ("Connect error");
    mysql_select_db('myDatabase',$connection);
    /* show tables */
    $res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES", $connection) or die ("No Show Database");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        echo $row[0], '<br/>';
    }

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

There is another page that takes username and password and then pass it to this page via POST method, But this page instantly shows me Connect error. I event tried it with an **if else** instead of the **or die** but still can't connect.

Comment: `or die ("Connect error");` doesn't help you. `or die(mysql_error())` will, same for `or die ("No Show Database");`

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php also

Comment: what's the goal here? Use POST arrays/variables and act as parameter for the db connection?

Comment: There is no (yet) any sql injection risk in this code.

Comment: It's anybody's game. Just like baseball; I am outta here. *Slide DiMaggio, sliiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide!!!* - Edit: batter up Sam! @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Right behind you Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the variables to the connection function and show a meaningful error description:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

/* connect to the db */
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
```

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

You really dont want to connect to your database in that fashion though, it leaves too much up to chance. And when you use passwords you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Unclean variables passed into database functions @vp_arth. I am trying to head it off at the pass.

Comment: if you about `user/pass` - its mean is to receive unclean variables(as is). But if you about query, how `show databases` without any concatenations can be at risk of sql injections?

Comment: He is not passing them to `SHOW DATABASES;` The OP is passing them to `mysql_connect()` and there is *no* possibility of SQL inject there. I am just cautioning the OP. It isn't a matter of "if" it is a matter of "when" the OP will send user data to their database.

Comment: Hm, ok) I just think, may be new hole was found in `mysql_connect`, say for very long password...  May be you know, that I don't :)

Comment: @vp_arth stranger things have happened in `mysql_` ;-)

Comment: I have another issue: where to find guys to fix `segmentation faults` inside `pdo_firebird` driver :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I see you were right all along Sam. I take it you've gotten your crystal ball back from the shop and all nicely polished, I might add ;-)

Comment: *Blind squirrels and nuts Ralph. Blind squirrels and nuts.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: @JayBlanchard Let's only hope those squirrels know how to aim Sam, unlike those "3 blind mice". I wouldn't want them to shoot blindly in direction of my "family jewels". *crunch*